# How can i encrypt a text to wpa2 password (MasterKey) in c#

Tags: c#, passwords, key, wifi

I'm trying to make a code that will try to crack WPA2 keys, As i'm thinking i should first convert the text-password that i want to try to a WAP2 key, than check if it's the same (like md5 or others),So i need to know how the WPA2 keys or passwords or what the called MasterKey made, please

Answer (score 3):

Try use this code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace WPA2MasterKeyGeneRator
{
    public class WpaKeyCalculator
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var keyCalculator = new WpaKeyCalculator("dlink");

            var key = keyCalculator.GetWpaMasterKey("1234567");

            //print hex
            //you can check results using online calculator here http://jorisvr.nl/wpapsk.html
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(key).Replace("-", ""));
        }

        private readonly byte[] _ssidBytes;

        public WpaKeyCalculator(string ssidName)
        {
            _ssidBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ssidName);
        }

        private byte[] GetWpaMasterKey(string password)
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2;

            //little magic here
            //Rfc2898DeriveBytes class has restriction of salt size to >= 8
            //but rfc2898 not (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)
            //we use Reflection to setup private field to avoid this restriction

            if (_ssidBytes.Length >= 8)
                pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _ssidBytes, 4096);
            else
            {
                //use dummy salt here, we replace it later vie reflection
                pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 4096);

                var saltField = typeof(Rfc2898DeriveBytes).GetField("m_salt", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
                saltField.SetValue(pbkdf2, _ssidBytes);
            }

            //get 256 bit PMK key
            return pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
        }
    }
}
```